# Scroll event bind using addEventListener on body does not work. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

In the following, the javascript's `scroll` event does not call the `function counter()` when the page is scrolled. Why?

**JS**

```
   $(function(){
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

            body[0].addEventListener('scroll',counter, true);
            var x = 0;
            function counter() {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x += 1;
            }
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Potentially because you haven't included jQuery and therefore `$` isn't defined and callin `$()` throws an error? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: No that's isn't the case, here the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v6nrqxqt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- set `height` property to the document, to make the scroll event actually possible
- `body[0].addEventListener('scroll', counter, true)` won't make any effects. `body` tag is the whole document - refer to the document instead
- it can be done without using `jQuery`

```js
(function() {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', counter, true);
  var x = 0;
  function counter() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x += 1;
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
#demo {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the scroll event to the global window object and make sure that a scrollbar is actually visible so that the scroll event fires.

Check the below code snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  var x = 0;

  window.addEventListener('scroll', counter, true);

  function counter() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x += 1;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
}

#demo {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) for more information